# How to update interop.activeds.dll virsion

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, vmware, vsphere

I have updated both `VimService2005.XmlSerializers.dll` and `VimService2005.dll` according to my visual studio version(2017) by referring [this tutorial](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.dsg.doc_50%2Fsdk_c_sharp_development.5.4.html).

Now I want to update `interop.activeds.dll` according to the above mentioned DLL files versions.

What is the best solution for this problem?